# CollapsingToolbarLayout not Collapsing with RecyclerView Scroll Behavior

Tags: android-recyclerview, scroll, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-nestedscrollview

I have a CollapsingToolbarLayout that shows an image (placed inside the ConstraintLayout to keep the ratio 1:1) and a RecyclerView that has the `com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior` attached to it.

[Image of Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHtR8.png)

The image is in green and the RecyclerView is in blue.

**The problem is when I scroll up on the RecyclerView, the CollapsingToolbarLayout doesn't collapse.** Instead, the RecyclerView just scrolls underneath the entire layout. I have to manually scroll inside the CollapsingToolbarLayout for it to collapse.

Here is the code for the layout:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I originally had the RecyclerView inside a NestedScrollView with the scrolling behavior attached to the NestedScrollView, but this was causing issues with the Adapter creating a ViewHolder object for EVERY single item in the RecyclerView and that was causing a lot of performance and lagging/freezing issues.

From my understanding, a RecyclerView should not be placed inside a NestedScrollView for this reason and that is why I took the NestedScrollView out.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Simply you should disable nested scrolling in recycler view

```
android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
```

Also, if you have nested recycler views you should disable nested scrolling in child recycler views.

Comment: This works if you have nested recyclerviews and the child one "steals" the touch events (which I did) so thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want the image to collapse when recyclerview scrolls, use this scroll flags

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
```

and use

```
app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior"
```

in your recyclerview , and `android:nestedScrollingEnabled` attribute is not required for what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

have you looked into https://www.journaldev.com/13927/android-collapsingtoolbarlayout-example

Also see some of the things you are missing